# Django multiple database

Tags: django, django-database

I'm using two same structure database in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
    'db_1402': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database2',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

and user select a database in login page. I want to use user selected database in whole project and all Models read and write in user selected database.
I try to use database router but user logout automatically. I define bellow decorator to save database name in `connections['default'].alias` and pass it to database router:

```
from django.db import connections
def db_login_required(login_url):
    def decorator(view):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                next_url = request.get_full_path()
                return redirect(f'{reverse(login_url)}?{urlencode({"next": next_url})}')
            connections['default'].alias = request.session.get('database', 'default')
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper_func

    return decorator
```

and then I create a database router like this:

```
class SessionDatabaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return connections['default'].alias

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return connections['default'].alias

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

but after login suddenly user logout automatically.
How can fix this?

Comment: How are you persisting the user selected DB with the user session? the user is being logged out because of the session being persisted in the DB most probably, and after the user logs in the DB is changed the logged in session is somewhere else.

Comment: in user login before authenticate function I  save user selected database name in connections and session```connections['default'].alias = database_name```, ```request.session['database'] = database_name``` @devdob